# How to read UTF-8 text from file using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, filestream

I have some problems with reading UTF-8 encoded text from file. My version reads only ASCII characters.

```
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
    QFile file("s.txt");

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    QTextStream in(&file);
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        qDebug() << line;
    }
}
```

s.txt:

```
jąkać się
ślimak
śnieżyca
```

output:

```
"jka si" 
"limak" 
"nieyca"
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See [`QTextStream::setCodec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-1):

```
in.setCodec("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried it and now all the non-ASCII characters are replaced with "?".

Comment: Perhaps your qDebug output console doesn't support those characters. That'd be a reasonable source of the "?". Try showing the string in a QLabel on-screen.

Comment: It's not the issue. dDebug() << QString("śnieżyca"); works perfectly.

Comment: You're sure your input file is actually UTF-8?

Comment: 4 text editors (Geany, jEdit, gedit, Kate) say it is UTF-8. And still I have my problem with "?".

Comment: OK, it eventually fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You shuold do:

```
QTextStream in(&file);
in.setCodec("UTF-8"); // change the file codec to UTF-8.

while(!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    qDebug() << line.toLocal8Bit(); // convert to locale multi-byte string 
}
```

Comment: After it I get: "j?ka? si?" "?limak" "?nie?yca"

Comment: What's your default locale? If `qDebug() << QString("śnieżyca");` works perfectly, it means your system configured a non-ASCII locale.  You should try `qDebug() << line.toLocal8Bit();`

Answer (score 2):

I was also having `????` when reading an XML file with `QXmlStreamReader`. I fixed it by calling this before reading the file:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```